# Why does virtualbox add 32 to return values

Tags: bash, command-line, virtualbox

I'm using virtualbox through command line to make visual unit tests on our enterprise c++ application. Everytime the app returns, i get the application code, which allows me to know if it worked or not using

```
echo "Result is" $?
```

We use the following command to launch our app with tests

```
vboxmanage guestcontrol $VMNAME $USERPASS run --exe $APPPATH --timeout 1200000 -- SAINETV4.exe -user $USER -password $APPPASS -procedure-exit-on-end -procedureOutput $PROCEDUREOUT -procedure $PROCEDURE
```

The applications launches, executes the tests, and returns. If the applications succeeds, the return code is 0. And thus we see in the console

```
Result is 0
```

However, everytime i input a non 0 value (we actually use 33 and 34) we get

```
Result is 65
Result is 66
```

Which is 33 and 34 plus 32. When using verbose mode to fine, virtualbox says that the return code is 32/33, but then returns it with +32

The documentation doesn't show anything about it. Why do they do that? Is there a way to get the true code by adding arguments to the given command line to prevent the addition?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This lets you distinguish between `virtualbox` returning an error, and `virtualbox` successfully running a program that returns an error. For example, <strike>an exit status of 2 would indicate that `virtualbox` was killed by `SIGINT`</strike> an exit status of 2 would represent some error by `vboxmanage` itself, but an exit status of 34 would indicate that the program being run by `virtualbox` was killed by `SIGINT`.

(If `vboxmanage` is killed by `SIGINT`, the shell reports an exit status of 128+2=130 for the process.)

Comment: Thanks but it doens't answer my question. It's obvious that the first error codes are reserved by virtualbox, but my question is specifically on where does it come from (any documentation, any explanation in code somewhere) and if there is a way to force the proper code. If it's not written anywhere, then it might change without warning for <insert reasons> thus breaking my code. You also talk about 128.. why 128? where does it come from?

Comment: Adding 128 is the POSIX convention for distinguishing between an actual error and being killed by a signal. Any other meaning for a non-zero exit status below 128 is defined by the process itself.

Comment: Short of any documentation from `vboxmanage`, you can only infer that 32+k indicates the process run in the VM exited with status k, as you have done.